# Unable to find API keys for 2checkout

Tags: 2checkout

I have been searching for publishable key and api key for my 2checkout account.
can someone tell me about this. how do i find my API keys,

1. publishable key
2. private key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to   **Integrations** and from there you should have automatically selected **Webhooks & API** then you can find your **API Keys** on **API** section.